# matplotlib multiple plots - show yticks for all subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a multiple plots figure, using this command (all subplots share x and y axes):

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=4, sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

How do I make the yticks to appear on all subplots (shown in red):
[image]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the tick labels for the yaxes on each plot to have the property `visible=True`

A minimal example is below:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=4, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for ax in axes:
    ax.plot(range(20),range(10,30))
    plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(),visible=True) # set property
```

Note that `setp` sets the passed in property on the object passed in as the first argument, or (if that object is iterable) each component of that object.  The `pyplot.setp()` interface is [documented here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.setp) and implemented as part of `matplotlib`'s `Artist` object - [code here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v1.4.3/lib/matplotlib/artist.py#L1245).

This produces:

[image]

Comment: I hoped that a shorter way would be available, like an argument to the plt.subplots function. But that also works. Thanks!